# Routes not working after deploying Laravel 5 project into hosting

Tags: laravel-5

I just uploaded my Laravel 5 proyect to the hosting server. The index page almost works, but every link is broken. Every single route returns an Internal Server Error message.
This is the actual message:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, and inform them of the time
>   the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have
>   caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while
>   trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I already set storage folder permissions to 777, but I don't even get an error log.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Read the server error logs and see what the *actual* error is...

Comment: This may be url-rewriting issue. Have you followed this? http://laravel.com/docs/5.0#pretty-urls ?

Comment: My hosting service does not supply error logs

Comment: My .htaccess works perfectly for Laravel 4, but not for Laravel 5.
I tried the instructions in your link, but it didn't work

Comment: I had to destroy my .htaccess and fix it back in order to the server to make the update. Thank you all.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In the end I could solve it adding

```
RewriteBase /
```

to my .htaccess file in the public folder.

This is my complete .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

The most strange thing is I already had tried that, because that's how I solved the same issue with Laravel 4. What made it work was changing

```
RewriteBase /
```

to the incorrect

```
RewriteBase ../
```

and then changing it back to

```
RewriteBase /
```

And misteriously it solved.

I hope this helps anyone. It's 5:22 and I need some sleep

Comment: I am facing the same problem, tried this but not yet working

Comment: I am only able to view homepage but other routes showing 404 (Using Laravel at plesk)

Comment: you just described the problem of this post. Did you already edit your .htaccess?

Comment: I used it as RewriteBase /admin-boilerplate  for my laravel project hosted via alias in httpd.conf file

Answer (score 1):

First make sure `.htaccess` file exists in your `public_html` directory. Most uploads via zip on linux server will not automatically copy the `.htaccess` file since it is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

You will encounter this problem if you missing the `.htaccess` in public_html which is not included if you compres the project to `.zip` or others.